# Method returns an objective-c object in SBJson

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok so I tried to read up here but I'm lost :(

I'm using the SBJson framework.  https://github.com/stig/json-framework

And from reading stack and other forums Im not using *object but I am right above my if statement.

Can some one shed some light please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
NSSting *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
```

to

```
NSSting *json_string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8Encoding] autorelease];
```

Comment: Great thanks.  I will research "autorelease" and releasing things in docs tonight.

Answer (score 0):

What's your question? The static analyzer is telling you that you have to release `json_string` after the line `NSDictionary *status = [object objectWithString:...`.

Answer (score 0):

You created (alloc/init) json_string, but did not release it.